# Is it easy to do IPC with wxWidgets?

Tags: wxwidgets, ipc

Is it easy to create an IPC setup with wxWidgets? I have an application that needs to detect if a previous instance is running and send a message to the running instance with a string value. Is there an easier way to do this than setting up a wxServer and wxClient-derived class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using wxClient and wxServer is really as simple as it gets, I don't think you can simplify it even further. Have you looked at ipc sample included in wxWidgets distribution?

Comment: After looking over the instructions, yes it is MUCH easier than it looks - the documentation and large number of methods for `wxConnection` scared me :)